# PHP session not available

Tags: php, session

I successfully create session and it works for all pages but when the following page is executed it does not display any session variable and asks for login again ..

here is the code:

```
if(!session_id())
    session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("0.0.0.0 ","db_name","pwd");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("db_name", $con);
if($_GET['rating']=='like')
{
    $rcount = $_GET['rcount'] + 1;
    $id= $_GET['id'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE networx_notes SET up='$rcount' WHERE id='$id' ");
    header( 'Location: http://adrress.com/somewhere.php' ) ;
}
```

Comment: what do you expect to happen and what happens?

Comment: Try putting `session_start()` at the top of the code

Comment: What's with the asterisks in your code? Is this supposed to be a comment?

Comment: write `session_start();` in separate file and include that in other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your session variables are not showing after the redirect `http://adrress.com/somewhere.php`, possibilities:

- You do not have `session_start()` before trying to access session variables on this page http://adrress.com/somewhere.php.
- The page http://adrress.com/somewhere.php is on a different domain than the referring page.
- There are no actual session variables set in the script containing your code sample (check with `print_r($_SESSION)` before the redirect.

Note: You should always `die` \ `exit` after a header location change.